# POSTing a file's contents with CURL

Tags: linux, macos, curl

(The following is backstory, you can jump down to "Question:" if you'd like)

[There's a webpage for one of my courses](http://matt.might.net/apps/pylex/) that accepts input text (expected to be Python code) and then gives some tokenized response. It's meant to be used as a reference for the Python lexers we're writing. I'm trying to automate my testing process and be able to check my code without opening a browser, copying text back and forth, etc. So here's what I'm trying to do:

I've got a sample python file named "x.py" and I want to post it to the server as if I had filled out that form. I've tried:

```
curl --data-urlencode "file=@x.py" http://matt.might.net/apps/pylex/pylex.php
```

But unfortunately, that's not working right because apparently `"@x.py"` is getting posted as my file contents (that is, `"file=@x.py"` is what's getting posted, not `"file=<contents-of-x.py>"`). I've tried `--form` and `--data` but those haven't worked either.

**Question:**
Specifically, if I have a file with non-url-encoded contents, and the contents of this file needs to be part of a POST and associated with a particular name (in this case, `file`), what's the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: [Just found one way to do it:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3269886/1287251) `"file=\`cat x.py\`"`

Comment: Why not post that as an answer? You can answer your own question, and then in ~2 days or something (not sure how long) you can accept it.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Alright, I'll post it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you want is `"file@x.py"` (no `=`).

From the `curl` [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> **name@filename** This will make curl load data from the given file
>   (including any newlines), URL-encode that data and pass it on in the
>   POST. The name part gets an equal sign appended, resulting in
>   name=urlencoded-file-content. Note that the name is expected to be
>   URL-encoded already.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave qmega's answer as the accepted one, but I'll put an answer I left in a comment here too for easier reading. One other way to do this is simply by specifyping `` "file=`cat x.py`" ``. For the full command, it would be:

```
curl --data-urlencode "file=`cat x.py`" http://matt.might.net/apps/pylex/pylex.php
```