# Posting file to pastebin via Batch with CURL

Tags: windows-10, batch, curl, pipe, upload

I am attempting to upload log files to pastebin using CURL.exe on a Windows 10 machine in a batch (.bat) file.

The following command **works**:

```
curl -X POST -d "api_dev_key=MY_DEV_KEY" -d "api_paste_code=this is a the text to send to pastebin" -d "api_option=paste" "https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php" -d "api_expire_date=10M"
```

However, it only allows uploading a **single line**, where as I want to upload an entire file. 
I tried:

```
curl -X POST -d "api_dev_key=MY_DEV_KEY" -T "logfile.txt" -d "api_option=paste" "https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"
```

But curl responds to this with "`Bad API request, invalid api_dev_key`".

I've found numerous options such as [Easy way to paste command line output to paste bin services?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108493/easy-way-to-paste-command-line-output-to-paste-bin-services), [POSTing a file's contents with CURL](https://superuser.com/questions/543762/posting-a-files-contents-with-curl), and [Bash Script to upload files and data to Pastebin.com](https://gist.github.com/jonguenther/e43977be33827ed45bc5b32a394cdf65) that allow you to either upload a file's contents to pastebin or pipe a command to curl as a post **on unix / bash**, but none of these work in batch do to a difference in handling pipes.

What is the proper way to post a logfile to pastebin from within a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make a multipart POST request (just as the API requires), but the `-T` option actually tells curl to use a *PUT* request instead. PUT is used exclusively for uploading a single file and nothing else; it does not allow for multiple fields. (That's what POST is for.) It does not make sense to mix the two.

So because you're working with a form, the file's contents *also* have to be submitted as a form field. The field name is `api_paste_code`, and the value can be loaded from a file using curl's `<` or `@` operators:

```
-d "api_paste_code=<logfile.txt"
```

In this case, you most likely should be using `-F` instead of `-d` everywhere, as the former generates a MIME multipart message that better supports large files (especially binary files), while the latter tries to put everything in a single urlencoded string.

```
-F "api_dev_key=MY_DEV_KEY" -F "api_paste_code=<logfile.txt" -F "api_option=paste"
```

(Generally the API service should accept both, although it's certainly possible that only `-d` will work.)